# How to get an integral that is real at the origin

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I am solving a differential equation with an initial value set for t=0. I need to do an integration.

```
iU[u_] := Integrate[1/(9 Exp[u] - 1), u, Assumptions -> Element[u, Reals]]
```

This give me a result that is complex at the origin:

```
-u + Log[1 - 9 Exp[u]]
```

The integral that the instructor wanted is

```
Log[9-Exp[-u]]
```

How to get Mathematica to give me a function that has real value at the origin?

Comment: `Integrate[1/(9 Exp[u] - 1), {u, -3 Log[2], u}]`.

Comment: Where did you get -3Log[2] from?

Comment: I tried this suggestion and still got Log[1-9Exp[u]] plus some imaginary component

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do a definite integral including the origin:

```
int = Integrate[1/(9 Exp[s]-1), {s, 0, u}, Assumptions->u>0]
```

> -u + Log[1/8 (-1 + 9 E^u)]

This differs by an arbitrary constant of integration from your instructors answer:

```
FullSimplify[Log[9-Exp[-u]] - int, u>0]
```

> Log[8]

*(Note that your original result also differs by an arbitrary constant of integration, although in that case the constant is imaginary)*:

```
FullSimplify[Log[9-Exp[-u]] - Integrate[1/(9 Exp[u]-1), u], u>0]
```

> -I π